# How do Is stop React App from resetting everything after submit form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to build a simple todo app but when I click submit on input for the form the page refreshes and all the data from the input is erased or lost, I am not sure.

console logs appear for a split second then they disappear after refresh. the array with list of todo seems to get filled with input but after refresh it disappears; or at least that is my understanding.

```
import React from "react"
import './App.css'
import TodoList from './components/TodoList.js'


class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    count:0
  }

  increment = () => {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count + 1
    })
  }

  decrement = () => {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count -1
    })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="App">
      <TodoList/> 
      
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

```
import React from "react"
import TodoForm from "./TodoForm"

export default class TodoList extends React.Component {

    state = {
        todos: []
    };

    addTodo = (todo) => {
        this.setState({
            todos: [todo]
        });

    };

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
        <TodoForm onSubmit={this.addTodo}/>
        {JSON.stringify(this.state.todos)}



        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

```
import React from "react"
import shortid from "shortid"

class TodoForm extends React.Component {

    state = {
        text: ""
    }

    handleChange = (event) =>{
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        })

    }

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefualt() 
        this.props.onSubmit({
            id: shortid.generate(),
            text: this.state.text,
            complete: false   
        })
        
        
    }
    

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
            <input
            name="text" 
            value={this.state.text} 
            placeholder="todo..." 
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
        </form>
        </div>
        )
    }
}

export default TodoForm
```

Answer (score 1):

Submitting a form does a full page reload by default. To avoid this you should call `event.preventDefault()` in the onSubmit method.

In this case it looks like you have a typo in `handleSubmit` method. The line `event.preventDefualt()` should be `event.preventDefault()` (*defualt* vs *default*).

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in event.preventDefualt(). It should be event.preventDefault().

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  I suggest to don’t answer unless you know exactly how to solve or properly answer what is asked for, when you'll get more reputation, you can comment, and in this case your answer normally would be better as a comment for clarification etc.  I tell you this so that you avoid getting down-votes! Have a look here --> [comment everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment#:~:text=What%20are%20comments%3F,they're%20gone%20for%20good.)